# Anybody explain meteor easy search for users collection with helper and event function with example?

Tags: meteor

Am facing a lot of problem in search & am new to development field.

Could anybody please help me...

Anybody explain meteor easy search for users collection with helper and event function with code example?

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a tutorial service.

Answer (score 0):

[This tutorial should help.](http://meteortips.com/first-meteor-tutorial/accounts/)

probably this website has all the basic thing to start you up with meteor tutorial. I dont know about others but this helped. [this is a good resource to take you forward.](https://www.yauh.de/best-learning-resources-for-meteorjs/)